# Java: How does converting a byte array to JSON String (which is to be converted into a JSON object) work?

Tags: java, json, websocket, binary, arrays

I came across an android tutorial and saw the following method which I don't quite understand:

```
public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
            int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }
```

The main pupose of this method is to convert a byte array received on a websocket into a json string,which is to be converted into a json object,like this:

```
@Override
            public void onMessage(byte[] data) {
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("Got binary message! %s",
                        bytesToHex(data)));

                // Message will be in JSON format
                parseMessage(bytesToHex(data));
            }

....

private void parseMessage(final String msg) {

        try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(msg);

...
```

How does the bytesToHex method work? I only know it loops through the byte array  and then perform a AND operation which keeps the byte the way it is(which I don't see the point of it). After that line,I'm lost. What does >>> do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, `j` is now `0`, and `bytes[j]` is now `1110 1111`.

`int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;` is equivalent to `int v = bytes[j];`, I think, because one byte takes 8 bits in Java and `0xFF` is 8 set bits (1111 1111) and 1110 1111 & 1111 1111 equals 1110 1111.

Now v is `1110 1111`.

`hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];` maps the higher 4 bits of v (`1110`) to char, and save it to `hexChars[0]`, since `>>>` is "move bits to right and fill with zeros", so 1110 1111 >>> 4 equals 0000 1110.

`hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];` maps the lower 4 bits of v (`1111`) to char, and save it to `hexChars[1]`, since 1110 1111 & 0000 1111 (0x0F) equals 0000 1111.

About why such a string can be parsed as JSON, I guess you have to read something about the array `hexArray` to find out how those integers ranged from 0000 to 1111 are mapped to char, so that you could know how the output string is like.